# change the type of the query result from DB2 via python

Tags: python, db2

I'm not able to use all the lines from my query output.

If I run the 1st code:

```
#1st code
l1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 'John'),(10, 20, 30, 40, 'Doe')]

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l1, columns=labels)

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
    A   B   C   D     E
0   1   2   3   4  John
1  10  20  30  40   Doe
```

If I run the 2nd code:

```
#2nd code
def c2nd():
    conn = ibm_db.pconnect("db login details;", "", "")
    sql = "SELECT * FROM METADATA.TBD_201811_TMP_AT"
    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
    tuple = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)
    while tuple != False:
            l = list(tuple)
            return l
            tuple = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)

 print(c2nd())
```

the output is ONLY one line instead of two:

```
[10,20,30,40,'Doe']
```

The problem is, if I try to write the result into the .csv file, I always receive only the last line of the result. How can I list out and use all (in my case both) lines of my output?

ps: just FYI, the result can contain 1000 or 100 000 lines too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `return` in your while loop, when the code hits that it breaks out of your function because it thinks it's done.

You can replace `return` with `yield` and it will pass out one item at a time in a generator.

Comment: many thanks Sven for your great and fast answer! The code is now working correctly!